# How do you update a local class variable in Python in a backtracking loop?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, backtracking

I am trying to append permutations of a list of integers to a local variable in python but end of appending a single permutation several times. The code will print all the results correctly but not sure why my class variable will not be updated correctly.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!!

I am working on a leetCode problem but can't output the right results. I am trying to update my array, myVals, within a backtracking loop but and storing the just one permutation.

I can print all the results however when

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVals = []

    def add(self, x):
        self.myVals.append(x)

    def permuteArray(self, nums, l, r):
        if l == r:
            print(nums)
            self.add(nums)
        else:
            for i in range(l, r + 1):
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
                self.permuteArray(nums, 1+l, r)
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]

    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        numCount = len(nums)
        start = 0
        self.permuteArray(nums, start, numCount - 1)
        print(self.myVals)

nums = [1,2,3]
driver = Solution()
result = driver.permute(nums)
```

Expected Results: 
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]

Actual Results: 
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Comment: Run the code locally and use a debugger with breakpoints

Comment: Thanks! Added x.copy() and it worked! Appreciate your comment.